# Display columns or specific records based on select option in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have code which has populated select dropdown both distinct values from mysql column and hard coded. When select `tester`, it correctly displays records for that `tester`.

Now I want to display some user defined columns in table when one of the hard coded option(which will be column name in mysql column) is selected by user. I'm new to php, so please need your help.

```
    <form name="frmdropdown" method="post" action="emp_dd_display.php">
    <h2 align="center">Records</h2>
            <strong> Select Option: </strong> 
            <select id="tester" name="tester" class="tester"> 
               <option value=""> -----------ALL-----------</option>
               <option value="machine_details"> Machine Details </option>
               <option value="tester"> Tester </option>
               <option value="test_event"> Event </option>
            <?php
                 $dd_res=mysqli_query($conn, "Select DISTINCT tester from workflow1");
                 while($r=mysqli_fetch_row($dd_res))
                 { 
                       echo "<option value='$r[0]'".($_POST['tester']==$r[0]?' selected':'')."> $r[0] </option>";
                 }
             ?>
            </select>
     <input type="submit" name="find" value="find"/> 
     <table border="1">
     <?php
       if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
     {
         $des=$_POST["tester"]; 
         if($des=="")  // if ALL is selected in Dropdown box, show all columns
         { 
             $res=mysqli_query($conn, "Select * from workflow1");
             //$res=mysqli_query($conn, "Select date1, tester from workflow1");
                 echo "<tr align=center>";
                 echo "<th>Sr. No. </th>";   
                 echo "<th>Date</th>";  
                 echo "<th>Tester</th>";   
                 echo "<th>Machine Details</th>";  
                 echo "<th>Event</th>";
                 echo "</tr>";  
                 while($r=mysqli_fetch_row($res))
         {                  
                 echo "<tr>";
                 echo "<td align=center>$r[0]</td>";
                 echo "<td width=200>$r[1]</td>";
                 echo "<td alig=center width=40> $r[3]</td>";
                 echo "<td align=center width=200>$r[4]</td>";
                 echo "<td width=100 align=center>$r[5]</td>";
                 echo "</tr>";
        }    
         }
         else
         { 
             $res=mysqli_query($conn, "Select date1, tester from workflow1 where tester='".$des."'");
                 echo "<tr align=center>";
                 echo "<th>Emp_Id </th>";   
                 echo "<th>Emp_name </th>";  
                 echo "</tr>";               
         }
           while($r=mysqli_fetch_row($res))
         {
                 echo "<tr>";
                 echo "<td align='center'>$r[0]</td>";
                 echo "<td align='center'>$r[1]</td>";
                 echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
    ?>
   </table>
   </center>
   </form>
```

Desired Output:

1. If nothing is selected i.e. "ALL" is set,

`----------------------------------------------------------
|   Sr. NO  |  Date   | Tester  | Machine Details| Event |
|10-05-2017 | testing1| Ganesh  |     dgrgr      | event1|
|10-05-2017 | testing1| Manoj   |     rewtw      | event2|
----------------------------------------------------------`

2. If user selects one of the `tester` (Ganesh),

`--------------------
|   Date    | Tester |
|10-05-2017 | Ganesh |
--------------------`

3. If user selects one of the **column** say `test_event`,

`----------------------------------------
|   Date    |  Event  | Machine Details|

|10-05-2017 | testing1|     abcd       |
|10-05-2017 | testing1|     ddfe       |

----------------------------------------`

Sample table data in SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8bd9/1

Comment: Are you having a specific issue? Is there something that doesn’t work?

Comment: No errors, but I couldn't figure out how to judge `post` value at this line: `$des=$_POST["tester"]; `. In my case it might be `tester` or `column_name`.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this, I have updated SQL Fiddle.